# Fuji Xerox DocuPrint CM405 df on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, printing

I'm trying to get a  Fuji Xerox DocuPrint CM405 df to work on my Ubuntu computer, but i'm running into a couple problems.

First off, the only driver listed on their website is a `.rpm` file, which (if I understand correctly) can not be installed natively. I tried changing the extension to `.deb`, but that didn't work either.

Their instructions also mention visiting `http://localhost:631/` in a browser, but I am not able to visit any site there. My browser just refuses to find anything.

How can I get this printer working?

Comment: the programme alien converts rpm files to debian format; so install with `sudo apt install alien` and then `sudo alien -i Fuji_Xerox-DocuPrint_CM405-1.0-5.noarch.rpm`

Answer (score 0):

the programme alien converts rpm files to debian format; so install alien with `sudo apt install alien` (that means you need to open a terminal and paste that command into it ....

then you need to get to the file so then 
`cd Downloads`

then `unzip fxdpcm405dfps12090lrpmfen.zip`
then `cd fxdpcm405dfps12090lrpmfen`

then `sudo alien -i Fuji_Xerox-DocuPrint_CM405-1.0-5.noarch.rpm`

and after that you can go to the PRINTERS folder and ADD a new printer; if ubuntu doesn't jump in and do it for you already; please let us know how it goes